# Excel Comments - Max Length in 2003

Tags: excel

Anybody know what the limit is for the comments on an Excel cell (2003)?  I'm programatically filling this in and want to make sure that I don't exceed the limit.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP051992911033.aspx) list all the Excel specifications and limits.

Not sure about comments, but it seems cell data is limited to 32767 characters. Also not sure of the character encoding or if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Looked up the BIFF specification for NOTES (which are actually cell comments) and there is not a limit per se, only 2048 per NOTES record, but you can have as many of these as you like, they are marked as continuation records past the first one.  With this in mind, it seems limitless.

However, to be safe, I'm cutting mine at 15,000 (as we should never need more than a 1000 for what we are doing).

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to give it a try by putting large comment programatically.

And I ended with result : 22877 chars. However I'm not sure whether character encoding matters.

Answer (score 0):

According to ["Excel specifications and limits"](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP051992911033.aspx) the the max number of chars is 32767 (only 1024 display in a cell).

I suspect that's characters on the assumption that no character ever takes more than 2 bytes...